# Place files with prefix in folder with number

Tags: powershell

I have batch changed multiple files that all start with a prefix of a folder where I need them in. 

The files are located on another location, like a folder on the desktop.

For example:

101AA0001.dat
101AA0002.dat
102AA0001.dat
102AA0002.dat

The destination folder will for example be: 
C:\destfolder\101\ or C:\destfolder\102\

Files starting with 101 need to go in the 101 folder and the files starting with 102 go to folder 102.

I can find some scripts that creates the folder based on the filename. But in this situation the folders already exist. I also know for sure the files don't exist, so I don't have to overwrite files or something.

I guess it is easy for the people that know PowerShell very well, but I don't know how to do this. Can someone please help me? This can save me a lot of time.

I have tried to move the files with the following rule:

```
Move-Item -Path C:\Users\Username\Desktop\test*.dat -Destination C:\Users\Username\Desktop\test2\ -include "*.dat"
```

But it copies the whole folder except for the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will take all files that end in ".dat" from the `$Source` folder into a subfolder inside the `$DestinationRoot` named for the first three characters of the ".dat" file.

```
$Source = "C:\Users\Username\Desktop"
$DestinationRoot = "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\test2"
$Filelist = Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Filter "*.dat" -File
foreach ($File in $Filelist){ $DestinationFolder = $File.Name.Substring(0,3)
         $FinalPath =  "$DestinationRoot\$DestinationFolder"
         Move-Item -Path $File.Fullname -Destination $FinalPath -Whatif }
```

Remove the `-Whatif` when you're ready to run it for real.

This doesn't handle folder creation and should error out if the file already exists in the target location so it won't accidentally overwrite anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that quite easily with code like below:

```
$sourceFolder = Join-Path -Path $env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath 'Desktop'
$destination  = 'C:\destfolder'

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -File -Filter '*.dat' | ForEach-Object { 
    $targetFolder = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $_.Name.Substring(0, 3)
    # if the target folder does not exist yet, create it
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $targetFolder -PathType Container)) {
        $null = New-Item -Path $targetFolder -ItemType Directory
    }
    $_ | Move-Item -Destination $targetFolder -WhatIf
}
```

The `-WhatIf` switch shows what **would** happen in the console without actually performing the move. If you are satisfied with what is output, remove that switch.